# Vaadin Plugin not working in Eclipse (Windows 8.1)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, vaadin, vaadin7

I've installed Vaadin Plugin to this computer using the instructions from https://vaadin.com/learn , and the installation itself seems to work just fine. However, when I'm creating a new Vaadin 7 Project and press Finish, the configuration menu doesn't disappear and it doesn't include Vaadin.jar and some other files in the project. This is how my project setup looks like when I press Finish:

http://imgur.com/ot49xgK

After Finish, it creates the project partially, and the New Vaadin 7 Project -menu doesn't disappear

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjpA0.jpg

This is how the project looks like (no vaadin.jar included):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JlQW.jpg

This is how it is supposed to look like I think:

http://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/4.0-nightly/translations/fi/html/img/intro/myproject-created.png

I've tried with different versions of Eclipse, different JRE:s, installing through the marketplace and directly through "Install new software...", having Tomcat as Target runtime (and without) and none of those seem to work.

Any tips how trying to solve this issue? I guess I'm trying with Ubuntu next if it would help. Thanks for any answers, help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with help from the Vaadin site:

https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4459919

Basicly the latest IvyDE-plugin (2.2.0 final) doesn't work, so by downloading previous version (2.2.0 beta1) Vaadin works fine.

But using Maven is probably a better solution anyway though :)